# Compiler can't find the function glMultiDrawArraysIndirect

Tags: c++, opengl

Has anyone successfully used glMultiDrawArraysIndirect? I'm including the latest glext.h but compiler can't seem to find the function. Do I need to define something (`#define ...`) before including glext.h?

```
error: ‘GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘glMultiDrawArraysIndirect’ was not declared in this scope
```

I'm trying to implement OpenGL superBible example. Here are snippets from source code:

```
GLuint indirect_draw_buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indirect_draw_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, indirect_draw_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER,
             NUM_DRAWS * sizeof(DrawArraysIndirectCommand),
             draws,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
....
// fill the buffers
..... 
glMultiDrawArraysIndirect (GL_TRIANGLES,  NULL, 3, 0);
```

I'm on Linux with a Quadro 2000 and the latest drivers installed (NVidia 319.60).

Comment: Tried GLee or GLEW or extension loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply `#include <glext.h>` and expect this problem to fix itself. This header is only half of the equation, it defines the basic constants, function signatures, typedefs, etc. used by OpenGL extensions but does not actually solve the problem of extending OpenGL.

On most platforms you are guaranteed a certain version of OpenGL (1.1 on Windows) and to use any part of OpenGL that is newer than this version you must extend the API at ***runtime***. Linux is no different, in order to use `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect (...)` you have to load this extension from the driver at runtime. This usually means setting up function pointers that are NULL until runtime in order to keep the compiler/linker happy.

By far, the simplest solution is going to be to use something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net), which will load all of the extensions your driver supports for versions up to OpenGL 4.4 at runtime. It will take the place of `glext.h`, all you have to do is initialize the library after you setup your render context.

Comment: Thanks Andon. I'm trying this now.. So far no luck.. My program compiles but when I make the first gl* call, it sets Program counter to 0 & crashes.  
        GLuint indirect_draw_buffer;
        glGenBuffers(1, &indirect_draw_buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, indirect_draw_buffer);

Even code which works without including glew.h crashes. I'm trying to resolve that and will let you guys know how that goes. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @andonmcoleman thanks for your suggestion.. I got this to work. (stupid me,) I wasn't calling glewInit (). Earlier when glew wasn't working, I tried setting up function pointer myself at run time & that worked too. I used glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glMultiDrawArraysIndirect") to get the function pointer & then made the call using this function pointer. Though glew definitely is much cleaner way to do it.